# Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating about the y - axis

Tags: calculus, volume

Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by

$$y=2x+6,\hspace{10mm} y=0$$

about the $y$-axis.

I have tried

$$\int\limits_0^6\pi\left(\frac{y-6}{2}\right)^2\,dy$$

but the answer is coming out incorrect.

Comment: If you are finding the volume of a solid by rotating a function about the $y$-axis, you will be integrating with respect to $x$, not $y$. Also, check the bounds on your integral...

Comment: @jm324354 I don't think that is accurate: when rotating a function about the $\;y\;$ axis  we can express $\;x\;$  as a function of $\;y\;$ and then the integration is wrt $\;y\;$ .

Comment: @Timbuc Ahh I do believe you are right as we are talking about the so-called "washer" method, so we are indeed integrating with respect to $y$. My apologies Adam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your integral is *almost* correct (observe that when putting $\;x\;$ as function of $\;y\;$ gives you the volume of a function between the zero axis and the function!). What did you get?

$$\pi\int_0^6\left[0^2-\frac{(y-6)^2}4\right]dy=-\left.\frac\pi4\frac13(y-6)^3\right|_0^6=\frac\pi{12}216=18\pi$$

Another way to see it: you're rotating a straight angle triangle, with leg of length $\;3\;$, around its other leg of length $\;6\;$, so you can "place" this triangle on the $\;x\;$ axis at vertices $\;(0,0)\,,\,\,(6,0)\,,\,\,(6,3)\;$ , and thus the hypotenuse is given by the line $\;y=\frac12x\;$ , and doing the volume-by-rotation integral we get

$$\pi\int_0^6\frac{x^2}4dx=\frac\pi{12}6^3=18\pi$$

Comment: This seems like it should be correct but when I input 18π , it still isn't accepting it as a correct answer.

Comment: @Adam I've nothing to tell you. I get the same also when I use the method of parametric curve: write the given line parametrically as $\;(t,2t+6)\;,\;\;t\in[-3,0]\;$ , so that the volume of the revolution solid around the $\;y$-axis is given by $$\pi\int_{-3}^0 x(t)\frac{dy(t)}{dt}dt=2\pi\int_{-3}^0t^2\,dt=\left.\frac{2\pi}3t^3 \right|_{-3}^0=\frac{2\pi}3\left(0-(-3)^3\right)=18\pi$$

Comment: Must be a mistake on the website, I'll go to the professor. Thanks for your help!